# Global navigation bar

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve to build a main navigation bar that stays permanent at the top regardless of visiting any page on my website?Basically, I am talking about a Global Navigation Bar.Please help me on achieving it. Thank You!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: just show with your example.I hope you are getting my point.I need a main navigation bar that stays at the top regardless someone visit any of my pages.For e.g. if someone visits my contact page then the main navigation bar should not disappear i.e.,the screen should not fill with my entire contact page.I need the main navigation bar to show.

Comment: You have to show what you've done, SO is not a code delivery system. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and try to edit your question so we can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You show no code of your tries...
This is kind of difficult to answer precisely.

But I think I can show you the track to begin.

You need to «fix» the position of a `div` on top of the page.
So if you have:

```
<div id="navBar">blah blah blah</div>
```

You can fix it on top of the page with this CSS:

```
#navBar{
    Position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

The second question is to show this navbar in all of your site's pages.
This will require some server-side scripting like `PHP`.

I don't know where you at about this...
Here is a tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/php/